# Return '0' when no results found

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to modify this query to return '0' in the Grade column if no records are found? Right now when nothing is found I get a blank row.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(Score, 0) AS Score, COALESCE(Grade,0) AS Grade, LAST_UPDATE, '' as  dummy
FROM (
SELECT (CASE ScanName WHEN '%=APP%' THEN '= Network System' END) AS   System, 
(sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 WHEN 4 THEN 3    
END)/COUNT(severity )) AS Score,
(sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 WHEN 4 THEN 3   
END)/COUNT(severity )) AS Grade, LAST_UPDATE 

FROM missing_internal

WHERE ScanName like '%APP%'

and LAST_UPDATE >= SUBDATE((SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE) from missing_internal), INTERVAL 1 day) 
HAVING System IS NOT NULL  
LIMIT 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL AS Score, NULL AS Grade, 0 AS LAST_UPDATE, '' as dummy

ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE DESC

)  as T2
LIMIT 1;
```

Score and Grade are the same on purpose as I am using a separate script to apply a letter grade to the score.

Comment: you mean you get a row with a System but no value in grade? or do you mean you get no row at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function ...

If i well understood your question the below query should do exactly what you want(getting zeros when now rows are returned) :

```
SELECT COALESCE(Score, 0) AS Score, COALESCE(Grade,0) AS Grade, LAST_UPDATE 
FROM (
SELECT (CASE ScanName WHEN 'APP' THEN 'Network System' END) AS System, 
(sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 WHEN 4 THEN 3    
END)/COUNT(severity )) AS Score,
(sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 WHEN 4 THEN 3   
END)/COUNT(severity )) AS Grade, LAST_UPDATE

FROM missing_internal

WHERE ScanName like '%APP%'

and LAST_UPDATE >= SUBDATE((SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATE) from missing_internal), INTERVAL 1 day)
HAVING System IS NOT NULL  
LIMIT 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL AS Score, NULL AS Grade, 0 AS LAST_UPDATE 

ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE DESC
) AS T2
LIMIT 1;
```

I have not tested the query, so you could need to arrange it ... However take the idea ...

If you want to get zero only when a column return null result, you can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in the same way as above example :

```
COALESCE(sum(CASE severity WHEN 1 THEN 10 WHEN 2 THEN 9 WHEN 3 THEN 6 WHEN 4 THEN 3   
END)/COUNT(severity ), 0) AS Grade
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for but I get this error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: Ok, yes the order by should by placed at the end, sorry my mistake, take a look at the updated answer and try again ....

Comment: Thanks for the update. I made the change and now am getting 'Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: ...sorry for the back and forth ...Thanks, now its telling me "Unknown column 'LAST_UPDATE' in 'order clause'" LAST_UPDATE is an actual column in the table

Comment: Query edited above, I am now able to display the zeros but now the 'system' column is blank'

Comment: Added to the first select statement: SELECT  COALESCE(System, Network System) as System ... also added CONVERT() around the score calculation to convert to a Decimal(10,2) ... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ELSE` to the `CASE`

```
(sum(CASE severity 
    WHEN 1 THEN 10 
    WHEN 2 THEN 9 
    WHEN 3 THEN 6 
    WHEN 4 THEN 3 
    ELSE 0
END)/COUNT(severity )) AS Grade
```

or use `IFNULL()`

```
IFNULL((sum(CASE severity 
        WHEN 1 THEN 10 
        WHEN 2 THEN 9 
        WHEN 3 THEN 6 
        WHEN 4 THEN 3 
        ELSE 0
    END)/COUNT(severity )), 0)  AS Grade
```